# Tomcat has error when use except localhost ip

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, tomcat

I have spring-boot application and angular. I will access outside server to application data. My angular is deployed on apache server and spring boot is on tomcat server. my ip for access out side server is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx when I use localhost my application run inside server but when use my IP to access outside server in application.properties tomcat has an error.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port = 8090
server.address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

This error is :

> tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8090 failed to start

Port 8090 is unused.

This IP is defined for a linux server

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled?  Or are you using AppArmor?  Both can stop an application from listening on "unexpected" ports.

Comment: i don't install selinux

Comment: It may have been installed as part of the base OS.  What distro are you running?

Comment: i using from apparmor

Comment: i am using from ubuntu server 18.04 lts

Comment: Check the apparmor rules to see if they are stopping you from using that port.  Also, use nmap or ss or netstat to check if something is already listening on the port.  (It is worth *checking* ... because your assumptions may be incorrect.)

Comment: This is most likely either a system admin or webserver config issue ... not a programming question.  You should ask it on an Ubuntu or UNIX Q&A site noto on StackOverflow.

Comment: i saw netstat but this port is unused.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://askubuntu.com/